# Integrate open source web mail clients to a web application

Tags: javascript, php, email, ember.js, webmail

I am working on a web application in which i want to configure a email feature. SO what I want to do is If My web app user want to send the email so user have to provide the IMAP or POP or SMTP settings first and then user will be enable for sending the emails. SO in the same way i want to open all the emails received on that user account.

SO i am looking for a open source mail client  for sending and retrieving  the emails from my web app itself.
Please let me know if there is any such email clients avail in free.

Our web application is based on Ember.js

thanks in advance.

Comment: gmail and hotmail both accept those inputs. you can right-click view source.

Comment: @dandavis : Yes they accept these inputs but we dont want the user to go to that application. It has to be all in one solution for the end user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

were you looking for something like this: http://emailjs.org/

> Email.js is a set of components that can be used to write email apps in pure JavaScript on the client in HTML5 or on the server in node.js. They can be used together or separately. Components include but are not limited to:
>
> an IMAP client: browserbox
> an SMTP client: smtpclient
> an email parser: mimeparser
> an email builder: mailbuild

Comment: emailjs changed it's location. now it's located at: https://www.emailjs.com/